# Add your package name to allowlist for adId/Privacy programmatically

Tags: android

By the following adb command, I can fix the error "Caller is not authorized to call this API. Caller is not allowed. " when AdIdManager::getAdId (Executor executor, OutcomeReceiver<AdId, Exception> callback) is called.

```
adb shell device_config put adservices ppapi_app_allow_list [package name]
```

How can I do it in my App programmatically ?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it related how the app is installed to the device?

Comment: the device is Pixel 6 with Android 14 security update January 5, 2024